# Can't get ng-show to work with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get this ng-show working but for some reason, it just won't. I have tried the following methods:

```
<div ng-show="s_quest.title > 0">Similar Questions</div>
<div ng-show="s_quest.title">Similar Questions</div>
<div ng-show="!s_quest.title">Similar Questions</div>
<div ng-show="s_quests">Similar Questions</div>
```

This is the code below that shows up when the similar questions are called.

```
<span ng-repeat="s_quest in s_quests track by $index">
    <span class="fullPadding">
        <a href="{{ques_cat_enum[quest.quest_cat]+'/'+s_quest.slug}}">
            <span>{{s_quest.title}}</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <br />
</span>
```

Where do you tink I'm going wrong?

Comment: you have a quotation mark out of place here  <div ng-show="s_quest.title > 0">Similar Questions</div> right after the "0".

Comment: You cannot use interpolation in anchor `href` directly. Consider `ng-href`

Comment: ngShow will hide the div is the expression is falsy or invalid. You can see what the value is by adding `{{ s_quest | json }}` inside the ngRepeat. Or inspect the scope using the console.

Comment: @Lorenzo von Matterhorn: nice name :P but can't figure out what quotation you are talking about. I don't seem to have missed anything there.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia: checking on it.

Comment: @cleftheris: Thanks.

Comment: @user3362364 lol Thanks.  In this line: <div ng-show="s_quest.title > 0">Similar Questions</div>. This ng-show="s_quest.title > 0"> should be this ng-show="s_quest.title" >

Comment: @ThinkingMedia: This is what I got when I ran your code {"id":14,"title":"What is available for people with disabilities?","slug":"what-is-available-for-people-with-disabilities","views":0,"question_category":"MU"}

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn: I tried that too. That was the second method I tried. It didn't work :(

Comment: That means `ng-show="s_quest.title"` should show the div. As a string that has a value is truthy. I would inspect your CSS and make sure `ng-show` CSS is working as expected.

Comment: @user3362364 I was just pointing out an error in syntax.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn: That's not an error in my opinion. I've used it many times in the past.

Comment: You should put up a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) please so that we can see the whole picture. I just tested and most of your tests (if not every single one) work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this code which worked:

```
<div ng-show="s_quests > 0">Similar Questions</div>
```

Thank You, Everyone for you time :)